# US tourism/business visa from non-resident country

Tags: visas, usa, ireland, business-travel, egyptian-citizens

I applied for multiple visas before (not US visa), but all of them were from my residence country. In all of these cases, I can get official paper which support my evidence (bank statement, letter which states I am employed with high salary, marriage certificate, security clearance, ...).

It is the same question as [Can I apply for and receive a US visa when residing in country other than my own?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5040/can-i-apply-for-and-receive-a-us-visa-when-residing-in-country-other-than-my-own), but I am not residing; I have a business visa.

case-specific details:
I am from Egypt, I have business visa for Ireland. While in Ireland, I want to apply for US business visa.

Why not to apply from Egypt? Because the waiting time is too long (75 days). The waiting time in Ireland in only 18 days. Both visits (Ireland, US) are short visits (3 weeks for each).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can apply for a US visa at any US embassy abroad even if you are on a visit visa. Process might be harder and they might ask for more documents but it is totally doable. From the [US embassy in Ireland website](http://dublin.usembassy.gov/nonresident-niv.html):

> Non-residents must follow the same application procedures as residents for a nonimmigrant visa, and you must provide sufficient postage for the return of your passport by mail.

In general, US Embassies around the world accept visa applications from any person whether the person is a resident of the country or not.