# Can I get us tourist visa if I apply for it from China?

Tags: usa

I am Russian and currently  I am in China on business visa. I am planning to go to Hawaii with my boyfriend for vacation. Is it possible to apply for us tourist visa from China and will we be able to get it or it's better to apply from my own country?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I apply for and receive a US visa when residing in country other than my own?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5040/can-i-apply-for-and-receive-a-us-visa-when-residing-in-country-other-than-my-own)

Comment: For me not a duplicate. The other question is about residence in another country, while this one asks about being a visitor in another country. Can be a big difference for this kind of things.

Comment: Something to keep in mind:  US visas generally involve a trip to the consulate for an interview--something that takes time.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike some other countries, the US does not *require* you to file visa applications from your place of residence. So it should be *possible* for you to apply from China.

If you have the option, it is generally *recommended* to apply in your country of residence -- that is, the country that you need to convince them that you want to *return to* after the vacation. Whether that is China or Russia is not entirely clear from your question.

Remember that it is your task in the visa application to document that you have so close ecomonic and social ties to somethere oiutside the US that it won't make sense for you to stay in the US as an illegal immigrant. Look at the documentation (bank statement, employment and so on) you have for those ties. If it's all in Chinese characters, you don't want someone at the embassy in Russia to try to make sense of it -- *and vice versa*!